# Nested UL LI to PHP Array - Incorrect Output in Array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree, html-lists

This is a follow-up to my question yesterday - [Recursive UL LI to PHP multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016257/recursive-ul-li-to-php-multi-dimensional-array) - I've almost managed to convert the HTML block to an array, though there is a slight problem that I cannot fix. When processing the HTML block below, the output array does not quite follow what has been inputted (and I cannot see where I'm going wrong and need a fresh pair of eyes!!).

I've included the following items:

- HTML Block
- PHP Function and Processing
- Output

**HTML Block**

Basically takes the form of:

```
-A
  -B
    -C
----
-D
  -E
    -F
----
-G
  -H
    -I
```

As follows:

```
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>C</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>E</li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>F</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>G</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>H</li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>I</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**PHP Function and Processing**

```
function process_ul($output_data, $data, $key, $level_data, $level_key){

    if(substr($data[$key], 0, 3) == '<ul'){
        // going down a level in the tree
        $level_key++;

        // check to see if the level key exists within the level data, else create it and set to zero
        if(!is_numeric($level_data[$level_key])){
            $level_data[$level_key] = 0;
        }

        // increment the key to look at the next line
        $key++;

        if(substr($data[$key], 0, 4) !== '</ul'){
            while(substr($data[$key], 0, 4) !== '</ul'){
                // whilst we don't have an end of list, do some recursion and keep processing the array

                $returnables = process_ul($output_data, $data, $key, $level_data, $level_key);
                $output_data = $returnables['output'];
                $data = $returnables['data'];
                $key = $returnables['key'];
                $level_data = $returnables['level_data'];
                $level_key = $returnables['level_key'];
            }
        }
    }

    if(substr($data[$key], 0, 4) !== '</ul' && $data[$key] !== "<li>" && $data[$key] !== "</li>"){
        // we don't want to be saving lines with no data or the ends of a list

        // get the array key value so we know where to save it in our array (basically so we can't overwrite anything that may already exist
        $this_key = &$output_data;
        for($build_key=0;$build_key<($level_key+1); $build_key++){
            $this_key =& $this_key[$level_data[$build_key]];
        }

        if(is_array($this_key)){
            // look at the next key, find the next open one
            $this_key[(array_pop(array_keys($this_key))+1)] = $data[$key];
        } else {
            // a new entry, so nothing to worry about
            $this_key = $data[$key];
        }
        $level_data[$level_key]++;
    } else if(substr($data[$key], 0, 4) == '</ul'){
        // going up a level in the tree
        $level_key--;
    }

    // increment the key to look at the next line when we loop in a moment
    $key++;

    // prepare the data to be returned
    $return_me = array();
    $return_me['output'] = $output_data;
    $return_me['data'] = $data;
    $return_me['key'] = $key;
    $return_me['level_data'] = $level_data;
    $return_me['level_key'] = $level_key;

    // return the data
    return $return_me;
}


// explode the data coming in by looking at the new lines
$input_array = explode("\n", $html_ul_tree_in); 

// get rid of any empty lines - we don't like those
foreach($input_array as $key => $value){
    if(trim($value) !== ""){
        $input_data[] = trim($value);
    }
}

// set the array and the starting level
$levels = array();
$levels[0] = 0;
$this_level = 0;

// loop around the data and process it
for($i=0; $i<count($input_data); $i){
    $returnables = process_ul($output_data, $input_data, $i, $levels, $this_level);
    $output_data = $returnables['output'];
    $input_data = $returnables['data'];
    $i = $returnables['key'];
    $levels = $returnables['level_data'];
    $this_level = $returnables['level_key'];
}

// let's see how we did
print_r($output_data);
```

**Output**

Note that D is in the wrong position, should be in position [0][2] - not [0][1][2], and every other position after D is out by 1 place (I'm sure you can tell by looking).

Basically takes the form of:

```
-A
  -B
    -C
  -D
----
  -E
    -F
  -G
----
  -H
    -I
```

As follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <li>A</li>
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <li>B</li>
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => <li>C</li>
                        )

                    [2] => <li>D</li>
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => <li>E</li>

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => <li>F</li>
                        )

                    [3] => <li>G</li>
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [2] => <li>H</li>
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => <li>I</li>
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thanks for your time - any assistance in outputting the array correctly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be *so* much easier if you’d use a [proper HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/292926/53114).

Comment: What do you mean? The HTML looks valid to me (I know there is no opening or closing <ul>, but if they are there it simply didn't start to process it). The reason why I've done it this was is so I can process the contents of the <li> items - where I will need to use regex, amongst other things...

Comment: Not the most helpful comment, but I would echo Gumbo here. I did a similar thing where I parsed an HTML table into a csv file, and simplexml was brilliant for it, the only hitch was that I had to make sure the HTML was well formed first, but that was just a matter of stripping out any attributes and making sure all tags were lowercase.

Comment: @dartacus `just a matter of stripping out any attributes and making sure all tags were lowercase` - really? *Just?* If you can parse through the string well enough to do that with guaranteed accuracy, couldn't you just have built your CSV table in the same process?

Comment: @DaveRandom You'd think, wouldn't you? It's a pro-tem solution until my content authors get around to making csv or xls files for people to download directly. You can see an example here: http://www.hesa.ac.uk/component/option,com_studrec/task,show_file/Itemid,233/mnl,11051/href,a%5E_%5ENHSBURSARY.html/ (at the bottom, 'valid entries')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF** your lists are always well formed, you could use this to do what you want. It uses [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) so it will *not* be forgiving of mistakes and bad form in the input code. If you want to be forgiving, you will need to use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) - the code will be a little more complex, but not ridiculously so.

```
function ul_to_array ($ul) {
  if (is_string($ul)) {
    if (!$ul = simplexml_load_string("<ul>$ul</ul>")) {
      trigger_error("Syntax error in UL/LI structure");
      return FALSE;
    }
    return ul_to_array($ul);
  } else if (is_object($ul)) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($ul->li as $li) {
      $output[] = (isset($li->ul)) ? ul_to_array($li->ul) : (string) $li;
    }
    return $output;
  } else return FALSE;
}
```

It takes data in the exact form as provided in the question - with no outer enclosing `<ul>` tags. If you want to pass the outer `<ul>` tags as part of the input string, just change

```
if (!$ul = simplexml_load_string("<ul>$ul</ul>")) {
```

to

```
if (!$ul = simplexml_load_string($ul)) {
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/Y28lEplA)

Comment: This looks good Dave - is it possible to have HTML within the <li> tags, passing that into the output array, rather than it being converted to XML, for example, if I had <span>Bla bla bla</span> - it would be preserved as this? So instead of B in the output array, it would contain everything that is not a <ul> if you see what i mean...?

Comment: @MrJ That is likely to break it. You could try replacing the line inside the `foreach` with this `$output[] = (isset($li->ul)) ? ul_to_array($li->ul) : (($li->count()) ? $li->children()->asXML() : (string) $li);` but with real world HTML you would be better with a DOM-based solution.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom - I'll bare that in mind if I run into any difficulties, would the DOM-based one be similar to the other answer?

Comment: @MrJ Thats certainly a very good starting point, I haven't analysed it properly but it looks on the face of it to be the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an working example for parsing the HTML, and turn it into an array, using DOMDocument and the domNodeToArray()-function provided here: http://www.ermshaus.org/2010/12/php-transform-domnode-to-array

The HTML didn't need to be well-formed.

```
// $inputHTML is your HTML-list as a string

// this is necessary to prevent DOMDocument errors on HTML5-elements
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

// UTF-8 hack, to correctly handle UTF-8 through DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $inputHTML);

// get the first list-element in the HTML-document
$listAsDom = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);

// print it out as array
var_dump(domNodeToArray($listAsDom));


/**
 * Transforms the contents of a DOMNode to an associative array
 * @author Marc Ermshaus
 * http://www.ermshaus.org/2010/12/php-transform-domnode-to-array
 * 
 * @param DOMNode $node DOMDocument node
 * @return mixed Associative array or string with node content
 */
function domNodeToArray(DOMNode $node) {
    $ret = '';

    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        if ($node->firstChild === $node->lastChild
            && $node->firstChild->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE
        ) {
            // Node contains nothing but a text node, return its value
            $ret = trim($node->nodeValue);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, do recursion
            $ret = array();
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
                if ($child->nodeType !== XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                    // If there's more than one node with this node name on the
                    // current level, create an array
                    if (isset($ret[$child->nodeName])) {
                        if (!is_array($ret[$child->nodeName])
                            || !isset($ret[$child->nodeName][0])
                        ) {
                            $tmp = $ret[$child->nodeName];
                            $ret[$child->nodeName] = array();
                            $ret[$child->nodeName][] = $tmp;
                        }

                        $ret[$child->nodeName][] = domNodeToArray($child);
                    } else {
                        $ret[$child->nodeName] = domNodeToArray($child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Standard practice is to actually include the useful code in the answer... why is there no code in the `domNodeToArray()` function?

Comment: @DaveRandom I assumed it is the same function as listed on http://www.ermshaus.org/2010/12/php-transform-domnode-to-array - but maybe you're right here

Comment: @feeela I gave this a try, but only returned the first 3 entries, not all 9

Comment: @MrJ That is, I'm guessing, because you used it on your exact code from above. The `$dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0)` refers to the first `<ul>` tag, which in the example above only contains the first three elements. If you wrap the string in `<ul></ul>` it should do what is expected. And feeela, you should post the whole code here - if that link becomes dead at some point, this answer won't be much use to future visitors, now will it...?

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks for doing so – my intention was not to bloat the answer, as the code can be found on the original site. Also there was no license information attached to that function – I just used it to demonstrate the example.